# Как отправить сообщение в ЛС сообществу VK API

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Как отправить сообщение в ЛС сообществу. Я получил токен через Kate Mobile. Отправлять сообщение в ЛС людям я могу. Но когда пытаюсь отправить в ЛС группе получаю Acess denied. Помогите плиз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Комментарий я оставлять не могу, по этому отвечу в надежде на то, что поможет.

Метод `messages.send` может принимать id получателя нескольким способами. Первый через `user_id`, `chat_id`, `group_id` и прочее (или это всё, не уверен). И при отправки сообщения нужно выбирать один из этих параметров. Второй же вариант `peer_id`, который является более оптимальным решением. Советую ознакомиться уже в вк то, как он работает.

Надеюсь помог, хоть и сомневаюсь.

p.s. ну или у Вы вообще не можете писать группе по какой-либо причине.